# TCL Bwidget: How can i pass my Combobox selected value to the -command

Tags: tcl, bwidget

May i know how to pass my selected value from the combobox to A_task through -command?
For example, if i selected 3 in the combobox, then i want to pass this value to my A_task proc

```
ComboBox .combo -values {"0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" \
                -helptext "Please select your options" \
            -command A_task

proc A_Task {value} {
   # Do something here
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's good news and bad news.

Bad news: you can't.

Good news: What you need to do instead is to get the command handler to ask the widget for the value, so your `A_Task` proc should look something like this:

```
proc A_Task {} {
    set value [.combo get]
    # Do somethng here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!
But it is not working :( is it i missed out anything?

Comment: Please describe the failure message, if any.

Comment: Seem like that is not working :(
Is it i missed up something?

    ComboBox .combo -values {"0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" \
                    -helptext "Please select your options" \
                -command A_task
    
    proc A_Task {} {
       set value [.combo get]
       puts $value 
    }